how to implement a no-login authentication system without using cache
I just want user to play with the webapp before signup. I feel like it's a common issue for startup but no one has addressed it well.
Currently the only solution I know is to implement a local cache before login, and then convert it to postgres format upon actual signup. but it's a pain because it's basically replicating the entire data structure, along with CRUD procedures in cache.
Is there a way to do it without cache. What about create a temperory postgres user using client's machine information (or ip), and attach actual auth info later upon signup. If so, how?
none of the idea here works.
